# Como utilizar el OR Expresion Languaje con tres parametros

Tags: java, jsf, jsp

Estoy utilizando `el` en `jsf` en la siguiente etiqueta

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{msg.fecha}"
 rendered="#{aperturaDoBean.dataItem6.idServicio ne 4 ||
             aperturaDoBean.dataItem6.idServicio ne 3 ||
             aperturaDoBean.dataItem6.idServicio ne 5 }" />
```

y el valor que tiene `idServicio = 4` y lo estaa mostrando, me poden indiqcar que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Además de lo que @hecnabae comenta llevaría la lógica de renderizado al backend para no cargar con lógica la capa de presentación, sobre todo cuando esta lógica puede ser potencialmente mucho mas compleja.

HTML

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{msg.fecha}"
 rendered="#{aperturaDoBean.msgLabelRenderingCondition()}" />
```

AperturaDoBean.java

```
protected List<Integer> invalidIds;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
   invalidIds = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5));
}
public boolean msgLabelRenderingCondition(){
     //Tu lógica aquí, en este caso sería:
     return !invalidIds.contains(dataItem6.idServicio);
}
```

La lista de identificadores inválidos se carga en el @PostConstruct por lo tanto nos aseguramos de cargarla una única vez luego de que se invocó el constructor de `AperturaDoBean`

Luego a partir del metodo `msgLabelRenderingCondition()` obtenemos la condicion de rendered.

Answer (score 1):

El problema no viene dado por `jsf` ni por `el`. En términos de lógica, el operador **OR** solo evalúa a `false` cuando todos los parámetros son `false`:

```
| A | B | Salida |
|---|---|--------|
| 0 | 0 | 0      |
| 0 | 1 | 1      |
| 1 | 0 | 1      |
| 1 | 1 | 1      |
```

Por lo tanto, si lo que pretendes es que el elemento no se renderize cuando `idServicio` adquiera los valores 3, 4 o 5, deberías utilizar el operador **AND**.